# Jquery Slider Rotates but something strange happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, orbit

I have a little problem, I've been working on this slider based on http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider (Orbit Slider) and Carousel plugins. You can view the results on my test page http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/localh0st# . As you can see the images are rotating, but this only works on Firefox for some odd reason. In Chrome the images rotate behind the background and I don't know why, also the caption are not rotating either.  Has this happened to anyone before? If anyone knows a possible solution to this, please let me know.

Here's the code I used to call the plugin

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $('#carousel').orbit();
 });
```

Thank you!

Comment: double check your `z-index`s and please don't use tables for layout. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is my suggestion for you. Check these `js` files on your page.

- cameramod
- jquery.easing.1.3
- jquery.min
- jquery.mobile.customized.min

they have some errors like `unexpected tokens ('<')` and your main html file's script also contain an error `#object has no method`. Try to correct these first. Not very major errors just spend some time on them, monitor them carefully using web developer tools. Happy coding :)